# On replacing the LJ-Speech dataset with your own

Tags: machine-learning, text-to-speech

In most github repositories for machine learning based text to speech, the LJ-Speech dataset is being used and optimized for.

Having unsucessfully tried to use my own wave files for it, I am interested in *the* right approach to prepare your dataset for an optimized framework to likely convert.

Answer (score 0):

With Mozilla TTS, you can have a look at the LJ-Speech script used to prepare the data to have an idea of what is needed for your own dataset:

https://github.com/erogol/TTS_recipes/blob/master/LJSpeech/DoubleDecoderConsistency/train_model.sh

Comment: Yes. It doesn't say much though. I tried cloning it with my material, yet it often does not convert.